# Groupbox check for changes event

Tags: c#, events, groupbox

I have a `DataGridView` and a `GroupBox` control containing a few `ComboBoxes`.
Depending on what is selected in the `ComboBoxes`, the elements in the grid changes.

Is there a way to say

```
If (Something Changes Within The GroupBox)
{
   //Update the grid
}
```

(Without writing a `OnSelectedIndexChange` event for every boxes)
I don't want the code for the updating part, I just need an event or something I could use to check if a the value of a control has changed within the `GroupBox`.
Any Idea ?

---

**Update**

Ok I think I didn't explained it the right way.
Forget about the `ComboBox`. 
Let's say I have a bunch of controls in a `GroupBox` is there a way to say :

As soon as the value of one of the control changes, create an event.

Comment: After reading your update, I would say you need to elaborate.  "Bunch of controls" is too vague, as they don't have the same uniform way of changing.  For example, the way a textbox registers changes (TextChanged) versus a NumericUpDown (ValueChanged).  I think what @Davenewza and I are proposing, where you have a separate method for managing change, and then calling that method in your controls various change events, whether by instance or by type, is the way to go.

Comment: I'm not looking for a workaround since I already have it working how I want it too. I just wanted to know if there was such an event and if not, understand why it does not exist. Now I understand thanks.

Comment: In my opinion, use a general solution (adding event handler) is better if you don't know how many controls you need in the groupbox or that bag is to big.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "something inside me changed" for GroupBoxes, but you can "cheat" and DYI like this (it's just a proof-of-concept without error checking and the sort):

```
// In a new Windows Forms Application, drop a GroupBox with a ComboBox and a CheckBox inside
// Then drop a TextBox outside the ComboBox. Then copy-paste.

// this goes somewhere in your project
public static class handlerClass
{
    public static string ControlChanged(Control whatChanged)
    {
        return whatChanged.Name;
    }
}

// And then you go like this in the Load event of the GroupBox container
void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    foreach (Control c in groupBox1.Controls)
    {
        if (c is ComboBox) 
            (c as ComboBox).SelectedValueChanged += (s, e) => { textBox1.Text = handlerClass.Handle(c); }; 
        if (c is CheckBox) 
            (c as CheckBox).CheckedChanged += (s, e) => { textBox1.Text = handlerClass.Handle(c); }; }
    }
}
```

Since every `Control` has its own "I'm changed!" kind of event, I don't think it can be any shorter as far as boilerplate goes. Behavior is a mere sample that writes the name of the control that changed in a ComboBox

Comment: Clear and exactly what I asked for. Thanks a lot. I'm not interesseted in such a workaround. I just wanted to know if such and event existed and if not, why. Now I understand. +1

Answer (score 9):

You could hook up each combo box SelectedIndexChanged event to one method:

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(GroupBoxComboBoxChange);
comboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(GroupBoxComboBoxChange);
comboBox3.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(GroupBoxComboBoxChange);
comboBox4.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(GroupBoxComboBoxChange);
```

Or using LINQ to setup an event handler for any combo box selection change:

```
GroupBox.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>.ForEach(cb => cb.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(GroupBoxComboBoxChange));
```

**Answer to your update:**  You are looking for a ControlValueChanged() event. I think the problem here is that all controls are different. What defines a "ValueChanged" event for a ComboBox isn't necessarily the same for a TextBox. It would be a semantic challenge and not very clear. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Ok so there is no way of using a GroupBox event for this ? It's weird it would be so usefull..

Comment: Nope.  It would be a very specific event in order for a GroupBox to handle the SelectedIndexChanged on any possible number of ComboBoxes.

Comment: Ha! I was thinking the same thing in my answer.

Comment: A SelectedIndexChangedOnAnyComboBox is quite specific because then what's stopping there from being a MouseMoveOnAnyTextBox or a DoubleClickOnAnyButton event... it would be endless.  To answer your update: You are looking for a ControlValueChanged<ControlType>() event.  I think the problem here is that all controls are different.  What defines a "ValueChanged" event for a ComboBox isn't necessarily the same for a TextBox.  It would be a semantic challenge and not very clear.  Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

GroupBoxes are usually just decorative unless they are managing radio buttons or check boxes, so expecting them to be aware of changes made to combo boxes is not something easily done out of the box.  If I may, why not code a method that does what you want it to do, and then call that method from all your combo boxes' SelectedIndexChanged events?